# Go back with HtmlUnit History

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to go back in history using HtmlUnit. I have the `History` object that contains the previous page but I am not sure how to get the actual `HtmlPage` so that I can do something with it.

Any ideas how I could get it from the `History`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have slightly edited your question to improve the formatting, and removed your use of a tag which said in its description "DO NOT USE THIS TAG". Your question is much more likely to get useful answers if you edit it to include a [minmal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as described in the [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

`webClient.getCurrentWindow().getHistory().back();`

Then

`HtmlPage backPage = webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();`